# Is there a difference in serial data formatting between Linux and Windows?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, serial-port, serial-console

I am trying to read in serial data from an RS-485 RFID reader using a RS-485 to USB converter found [here](https://leeselectronic.com/en/product/18268-usb-to-rs-485-adaptor.html) and a python script running Pyserial.

The issue I'm facing is that when I print out what is read, the right amount but incorrect bytes are displayed in my python terminal on Linux running Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. However when I test it on Windows the correct bytes are displayed. I use the exact same code, same hardware (other than OS), and the same reader settings.

My code for Windows:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('COM6', 19200, timeout = 2, parity = serial.PARITY_EVEN)
time.sleep(2)

while True:
    while(ser.in_waiting > 0):
        x = (ser.readline().hex())
        print(x)
```

Windows output:

```
020308fe10807c000bcbae9b9e
```

My code for Linux:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 19200, timeout = 2, parity = serial.PARITY_EVEN)
time.sleep(2)

while True:
    while(ser.in_waiting > 0):
        x = (ser.readline().hex())
        print(x)
```

Linux output:

```
0203081e1a001c030b0b1d131e
```

So in both scenarios I get 13 bytes (2 digits per byte), which I converted into a string. The only data that I care about and 100% know should be the same is the RFID tag data which are bytes 8 to and including 12 (000bcbae9b on the windows output). However on the Linux output the data is different (030b0b1d13).

Note: I know that bytes 8 to 12 (not counting from 0) correspond to my tag data because after converting the windows hex value to decimal, the number matches my tag and also the datasheet says.

So does anyone have any idea of why the data is different? Might it be because the systems see/format or interpret the data differently?

Thanks for the help!

The output of stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -a

```
onecup@inventory03:~$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -a
speed 19200 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 0; time = 0;
parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany imaxbel -iutf8
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl -onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
-echoctl -echoke -flusho -extproc
```

For easier visual reference here are the two byte streams again, but spaced and aligned:

```
Byte nr:  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
Windows: 02 03 08 fe 10 80 7c 00 0b cb ae 9b 9e
Linux:   02 03 08 1e 1a 00 1c 03 0b 0b 1d 13 1e
```

For additional reference here is the output of a different RFID tag. (bytes 8 to 12 are still the only ones I care about and windows is correct where linux is wrong):

```
Byte nr:  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
Windows: 02 03 08 fe 2e 80 7c 00 0b bb 9a 80 4b
Linux:   02 03 08 1e 16 00 1c 03 0b 17 1a 01 09
```

Comment: Please post the output of stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -a and also please use ser.read(Bcount) preferably to ser.readline since ser.read fits better to binary data exchanges ( vs ASCII only)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I posted the output above. Also I have already tried using ser.read() but found that the data remains the same as if I used ser.readline(), but I will change it.

Comment: It's much easier to compare the data received when you separate the bytes with a space and have Windows & Linux outputs on adjacent lines in your question, vertically aligned

Comment: If you're expecting even parity how can you receive valid byte values `0b` and `cb`?

Comment: @roaima : -inpck

Comment: @MC68020, your suggested `-inpck` disables parity checking, and there's also `-ignpar -istrip` set, so I can see why the bytes are presented. But unless the line or hardware is flawed - which I would suggest is unlikely given the short lengths and relatively low speed - I still don't see why the code should be reading a couple of bytes where one has the correct parity but the other does not.

Comment: XanderSoriano how many stop bits are given?

Comment: And additionally confirm cs8 (character size). BTW, RS-485 devices I know default to the most common parity : none. Please check.

Comment: @roaima I don't understand … the parity bit is added to the data bits, so you can transmit and receive any byte. `0B` will simply have the parity bit set to result in even parity: `1 1101 0000 1 0` (start bit, data bits starting with lowest, parity bit, stop bit).

Comment: @roaima Sorry about the formatting I'll remember for next time. I just assumed there was only 1 stopbit, that information was never provided. However, even when I specify/change the number of stop bits in the serial class call (i.e. serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', ... , stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_TWO)) to 1, 1.5 or 2 the output of the program remains the same

Comment: @MC68020 by character size do you mean bytesize? If so it is 8bits per byte. However if not, this information was also not provided. In terms of the parity I know its even because I set it with a demo program the suppliers gave me. Also, when I change the parity type in the class call the output also remains the same regardless if I set it to even, odd, none, mark and space.

Comment: The stopbit setting should only affect transmission. I don't know of any UART implementation that would ignore a new startbit coming too early, so this should not have any effect. But changing parity is supposed to have an impact. This makes me wonder if something goes wrong in the driver.

Comment: As already hinted there should be no difference between windows and linux if everything is configured correctly, however default configurations may differ.  You may want to review the datasheet for your RFID reader to see if it specifies start/stop/parity/data bits. I also wouldn't rule out hardware unless you are running Windows and Linux on the same hardware.

Comment: If it does nothing good, it won't harm anyway, flush the input buffer right after setting the serial port parameters. (reset_input_buffer())

Comment: @MC68020 that also did not work unfortunately. Not sure if this helps but I did hook my RFID reader to my arduino uno with a RS485 to ttl converter and was able to get the correct data there as well (on the arduino IDE serial monitor). So I'm guessing it really is just an issue on the Linux end.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Yeah I didn't think there would be a difference either. The datasheet doesn't reveal any specifics about the start and stop bits. However, I don't think it would matter, since on windows with the same serial port parameters (set by the class call), I was able to get the correct data. So whatever settings I have set already in windows works for the reader. Those settings are also same on the linux program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after more looking I found that it was a problem with the driver. The solution was to update or install a patched version of the CH341 driver.

Instructions found [here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ch340-drivers/all).

I don't fully understand what was wrong but according to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68192268/jetson-xavier-nx-unreadable-pyserial-usb), there might have been an issue with the parity checking of the USB to RS485 converter. Thanks for all the help!

Note: For my system the solution in the second link gave errors and didn't work.